# How to obtain a function from a implicit equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have

```
(60 - r/2) (70 - ca - r/2) - (60 - r/2 - ca + (4/25) (70 - r/2 - ca))*(70 - r/2)==0
Reduce[%, {ca}]
```

But How could I obtain directly a function as  ca[r_] :=...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eq = (60 - r/2) (70 - ca - r/2) - (60 - r/2 - ca + (4/25) (70 - r/2 - ca))*(70 - r/2) == 0
sol = Solve[eq,ca];
caFun[r_] := Evaluate[ca /. sol[[1]]]
caFun[r]

(* ((-19600 + 280 r - r^2)/(2 (-265 + r)) *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use `Reduce`:

```
expr = (60 - r/2) (70 - ca - r/2) - (60 - r/2 - 
       ca + (4/25) (70 - r/2 - ca))*(70 - r/2) == 0;
caf[u_] := (ca /. (ToRules@Reduce[expr, ca])) /. r -> u
```

So `caf[r]` yields:

```
(-19600 + 280 r - r^2)/(2 (-265 + r))
```

Comment: I only use Reduce because Solve gives me an error message with word numerrizating or similar.